# cannot resize child element to the full width of its parent

Tags: jquery-ui

Why I cannot resize `child` element to the full width of its parent? About 10 or 20 px is always missing to the full width.

```
<div id='parent'>
<div id='child'>CHILD</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#parent{
  width:450px;
  height:320px;
  margin:0;
  background:lightgreen;
}
#child{
  width:120px;
  height:45px;
  margin:0;
  background:gold;
}
```

**js**

```
$("#child").resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    containment: "#parent"
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/d3af6mmf/)

Comment: I am able to resize it to full width using your fiddle.

Comment: @NikhileshKV, how it is possible? I'm trying in Chrome and Opera and without success .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think there is a problem with using containment and aspectRatio. Maybe it can't keep ratio for the last pixels because resizing is not pixel per pixel.

In order to fix it, you can use the code bellow , it works.

```
$("#child").resizable({
   aspectRatio: true,
   maxWidth: $("#parent").width()
});
```

If the height could be bigger than width, you can add

```
maxHeight : $("#parent").height()
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d3af6mmf/2/)